# How to create plus [+] minus [-] toggle that expand list of links and that is compatible with Opera Mini?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can toggle div that expands informations and links with javascript to save some display space.
But the problem is on Opera Mini, it always has to reload the page before applying JS to Opera Mini Server. But when using Opera Mini, I see it done without refreshing the page on stackoverflow's footer:

```
[+] Stack Overflow [54]
site design / logo ...
```

When I click:

```
[-] Stack Overflow [54]
    Stack Overflow
    Server Fault
    ...
site design / logo ...
```

How can I achieve the same on some part of my mobile template?

My edit: I apologize for not being clear and not specifying the codes I have actually. I almost never post in stack overflow, but I'm not a beginner in programming.

The fact is the code I have for toggle menu, comment editing and displaying any other objects works normally with Opera Mini, as Opera Mini send the js request on Opera server which executes it and then send back the modification on Opera Mini.

But my own codes doesn't apply here, cause I know they won't work in Opera Mini without refreshing the page. On this Website's footer (stackoverflow.com) as this image shows :[Stackoverflow on Opera Mini 7.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LQN3.jpg)

it doesn't send any request to Opera server, but instead the app manage to handle it locally.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you're using now? That might help us.

Comment: I didn't make any on the footer yet for mobile. But with toggle code on the drop down menu, it won't work with Opera Mini.

Comment: Right, so what is the code you have right now that doesn't work with Opera Mini? We need context to work with in order to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Check this fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/22ZyM/3/ , and visit Stack Overflow site both on opera mini, and you'll see the difference in reloading.

Comment: I've edited my Question and added an image of it in Opera Mini! If you can verify it in Opera Mini, then you'll see the toggling without refreshing the page.

Comment: I haven't been able to find that anywhere on stackoverflow while using opera mini. According to their documentation, the page is reloaded whenever a click event or onChange event is fired from javascript, and there's no way around it. The browser doesn't actually handle any javascript itself, and just renders a snapshot of the page that is sent from their proxy server. [More info in the docs](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/#javascript)

Comment: Thank you for your effort ShamSUP. I just found out why! It wasn't HTML-CSS-Javascript issue. It's just the way Opera Mini handle <ul> that contains at least 10 <li> with <a> that contains href value. Opera Mini just hide them, but it's specific to them. See it on Opera Mini: https://jsfiddle.net/jbutvdfj/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to post the Solution in case anyone would like to understand this strange behaviour. The problem was not from HTML, CSS and JS, but from the Opera Mini handle html.

By chance I found another Website that had the toggle in Opera Mini http://www.file-extensions.org/convert-obml-to-html, and I decided to inspect the element. And I saw just simple unordered list (ul) where used.

Solution: When Opera Mini find (ul) that contains at least 10 (li) and each (li) contains (a) with href like (a href="any_value"), the browser just collapses them automatically to save space.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" >Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Link4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Link5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Link6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Link7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Link8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Link9</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" >Link10</a></li>
</ul>
```

Just that, only HTML. Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbutvdfj/9/).

In the case you couldn't find it on Stack Overflow's footer with Opera Mini, just click the full site link in the footer while in Opera Mini, the full site has so many ul li links that Opera Mini collapsed them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without js you can use a checkbox.

```
.checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox + label:before {
    content: "+";
}
.checkbox:checked + label:before {
    content: "-";
}
.checkbox + label + ul {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox:checked + label + ul {
    display: block;
}
```

.

```
<input id="togglelist" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="togglelist">Open/Close links</label>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a great way to do it without js, I will use those codes from now! But it still doesn't toggle on Opera Mini. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/etu4opw2/

Comment: That's strange, tried the code in a empty html document instead of jsfiddle? Maybe opera mini doesn't like jsfiddle.

Comment: you might be right. Opera mini can't test my local server, so I will push the codes to my staging server and see if it works.

Comment: I've tested it in my Staging server with Apache 2.4.10 on Ubuntu 14.04. It works on js mobile browser like Opera Mobile, but not Opera Mini. I will try to read the OBML and see if I can find any hint on their markup.